# Throwing both main exception and sub-type, is there a proper way?

Tags: java, exception

Okay, so I have a bunch of exception related questions across SO and Programmers, but there's just so much to ask, and either I don't know what to type, or not that many people have asked.

So, let's say I have a method that throws a `FileNotFoundException` (FNFE). I then have another method that uses the first one, but also throws a `IOException` (IOE).

My handler would catch both and do different things with each, but my IDE (IntelliJ) is signaling I have "a more general exception, 'java.io.IOException', in the throws list already".

I know it works if I do this:

```
public File openOrCreate(String pathStr) throws FileNotFoundException,
                                                IOException {
    try {

        // Method that generates the FNFE
        Path path = ReposioryProposition.getPath(pathStr);
        File file = path.toFile();

    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        throw fnfe;
    }

    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();  // IOE
    return file;

}
```

But do I need to do it explicitly? Will it work without, or more dangerously, will ***sometimes*** work without the explicit version.

To make sure we are on the same page, this is how I initially wrote the thing:

```
public File openOrCreate(String pathStr) throws FileNotFoundException,
                                                IOException {

    Path path = ReposioryProposition.getPath(pathStr);
    File file = path.toFile();

    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
    return file;

}
```

But I am unsure what happens, is the FNFE thrown or swallowed up ? My intention is to catch them separately and do different stuff for one over the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have to include the more general exception in your `throws` list. This already specifies that the method may throw any subclass of this exception.

In particular, you must handle the more general exception anyway, and this exception handler will also handle the subclass. If you want to handle the subclass explicitly, you have to catch it before the more general exception:

```
try {
    ...
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle subclass
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle general exception (this will not be executed if the
    // exception is actually a FileNotFoundException
}
```

Comment: Aha. Yes, that makes sense. I just throw the general one and I can catch all the others. This liens up with what I've seen in the java source code: A lot of throws IOException, but the documentation also mentions other exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

**It's perfectly fine to omit the FileNotFoundException from the throws clause if you already have IOException in it.**

Doing so doesn't affect the behaviour at all. FileNotFoundException will still be thrown, and you can catch it explicitly (as well as also having a different, more general, catch of IOException).

Having IOException in the throws clause simply states that *IOException or any of its subclasses* will be thrown from this method. FileNotFoundException is included in that.

Answer (score 0):

> But do I need to do it explicitly? Will it work without, or more dangerously, will sometimes work without the explicit version.

**Yes.** You have to do it explicitly, because it is a **checked exception.**

---

**Directly throwing back the exception:**
If you just add those checked exception to your methods signature, meaning if you add throws clause in method heading like `throws IOException`, then you need not to catch anywhere in your method.

But doing this has one flaw, If you are accessing n files line by line in your code and each line may throw IOException, if the exception is raised. You must **close the file** `.close()` before throwing it back to the called method. So using only this throws clause will not let you to do it.

So, just catch the exception and do necessary action either in [catch or finally block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

Only if no action is needed from your side and also if you want the exception to be popped out to the called method and the called method handles it, only then add the throws signature to the method.

Comment: I get that it's a checked exceptions (I obviously need to read more about them) but then, the fact that my "sub-method" (method A) throws it explicitly, but my other one (method B) does not, creates a problem ?

Comment: Check this doc, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html FileNotFoundException is extended from IOException. You can always catch the root exception i.e. IOException which will handle for both.

Comment: That's the problem, in my case IOE warns me something completely different than file not found. As in the file can be found, but there are read errors, I would handle both cases differently. I will read the doc though.

Comment: Since IOException is already in the throws clause, adding FileNotFoundException adds nothing to it.

Comment: I understand that now from the other answers, but thanks for clearing it out.

Comment: @Kalec Updated my answer. check if it is helpful.

Comment: Still wrong. You DO NOT have to add FileNotFoundException to the throws clause because IOException is already in it.

Comment: @DJClayworth where did I mentioned to add FileNotFoundException to the throws clause?. The meaning of "Yes" is either we have to catch the exception or add signature, we are not allowed to do neither of things. I know if you catch root Exception or even Throwable we need not to add-throws/ catch other exceptions. I just explained in the second half what will be the problem/issue we may face if we do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Java Language Specification has to [say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1):

> If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with (§5.2) a
>   catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement,
>   **then the first (leftmost) such catch clause is selected**. The value V
>   is assigned to the parameter of the selected catch clause, and the
>   Block of that catch clause is executed, and then there is a choice:
>   ...

(Emphasis and ellipsis mine).

Therefore, if you want your more specific `catch` clause to be executed, you have to place it first in the catch list.

Comment: That I did know, I was just very confused on the throwing part. But now I get it: Throw the more general exception only, but catch all if you like, but do it before the general exception. So in this case throw i/o exception, but catch file not found THEN i/o

Comment: This wasn't what was asked.

Answer (score -2):

you can catch first the sub class exception if not, then the general exception class like this

```
try{
      // something
   } catch(FileNotFoundException fne){
      // Handle the exception here
   } catch(IOException ioe) {
      // Handle the IOException here
   }
```

Comment: This wasn't what was being asked.

Comment: why not Hopjee answered the same after me. strange still he got 3 useful votes hhh

Comment: The question was about the throws clause, which you didn't talk about.

Comment: do i have to answer all, i can answer the part that i know about it, what's important is that it's useful